# (re)number numbered lists in emacs (muse)

Tags: emacs, elisp

suppose I have a text list in emacs like this:

```
a
b
c
...
d
```

Is there a way to assign numbers to those items in Emacs, by selecting the region? End results should look like:

```
1. a
2. b
3. c
j. ...
n. d
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(defun number-region (start end)
  (interactive "r")
  (let* ((count 1)
     (indent-region-function (lambda (start end)
                   (save-excursion
                     (setq end (copy-marker end))
                     (goto-char start)
                     (while (< (point) end)
                       (or (and (bolp) (eolp))
                       (insert (format "%d. " count))
                       (setq count (1+ count)))
                       (forward-line 1))
                     (move-marker end nil)))))
    (indent-region start end)))
```

Answer (score 11):

The way I do this, which may not be optimal, is to use regex search and replace.  This, of course, requires that you be able to define a regex to match the start of the lines you want numbers on.  Taking your example, I'd use a search regex like this:

```
\([a-z]\)
```

note the capturing brackets, we'll need that first letter soon.  And a replace regex like this:

```
\#. \1
```

where:

`\#` is a special form which is replaced, by Emacs, by the right number (though see the warning below);

`.` writes a stop; and

`\1` writes a space and the captured group.

WARNING: Emacs will number your items `0, 1, 2, ...`.  Until someone posts to tell us how to start at 1, I always insert a dummy 0th element before the edit, then delete it.

Comment: If you use `\,(1+ \#).` for the replacement that will start from one.  You can use arbitrary lisp expressions in replacements now, so that one just says replace with 1 plus the match number.

Comment: Thanks @Singletoned, I knew that someone on SO would sort that problem out for me.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [the Emacs Keyboard Macro Counter](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macro-Counter.html#Keyboard-Macro-Counter).

- Put the cursor one line ABOVE your list.
- Start a macro: `F3`
- Insert the counter value: `C-x C-k C-i`. A 0 will appear
- Insert the DOT and a space: `.`
- Move  the cursor to the next line
- Stop the macro: `F4`
- Select your list
- `M-x apply-macro-to-region-lines`
- You can delete the 0 you added on the top and enjoy :)

**NOTE:** This will create a numbered list. It will not use letters.

Comment: awesome. You can also set the counter using `C-x C-k C-c` or `kmacro-set-counter`.

Answer (score 7):

A much simpler way is to use the [CUA](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CuaMode) library's advanced rectangle editing commands. CUA is included in Emacs (at least 23.1, I think it's in earlier versions as well), so there isn't any new code to get.

You can use `cua-set-rectangle-mark` (bound to C-Return by default) to start a rectangle, and then use `cua-sequence-rectangle` to insert increasing values. It also gives you control over the format and starting value, so there is a lot of flexibility.

As an aside, CUA is primarily designed to make Emacs operate more like standard text editors (with C-c for copy, C-v for paste, etc), but it also includes some unrelated niceties, like rectangle editing. Don't ask me why :). If you want to use the rectangle editing without enabling the CUA keybindings (which is what I do), set `cua-enable-cua-keys` to `nil`, which can be done via customize.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some elisp code to do it; would be easy to customize if you like tinkering.

This will number the current region (unless it is already numbered), and also the last line binds to the M-n keys. You could use a function key "[F6]" as needed.

Modified to take a format string to use. The default is 1. but you could do something like %d) to get a bracket instead of a . and so on.

```
  (defun number-region(fmt)
  (interactive "sFormat : ")
  (if (or (null fmt) (= 0 (length fmt)))
      (setf fmt "%d. "))
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (narrow-to-region (point) (mark))
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (let ((num 1))
    (while (> (point-max) (point))
  (if (null (number-at-point))
      (insert (format fmt num)))
      (incf num)
      (forward-line))))))


(global-set-key "\M-n" 'number-region)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but if you find yourself manipulating numbered lists frequently, you may want to look into [org-mode](http://orgmode.org/). In particular, the [section on plain lists](http://orgmode.org/manual/Plain-lists.html#Plain-lists).

Comment: Yes, org-mode specific, but exactly what I was looking for.  `M-Up` `M-Down` to order the list.